# VBA to cycle through a column getting the ranges for the first 10 (Or max if less than 10) for each location

Tags: vba, excel

I am basically trying to grab the ranges for the top ten rows of each location, if there are less than ten then it would use the max ranges

For example with the data below if it is put in column A, then the first range would be A2:A11 the second range would be A14:A16 and the third would be A17:A26

```
Location
London
London
London
London
London
London
London
London
London
London
London
London
Liverpool
Liverpool
Liverpool
York
York
York
York
York
York
York
York
York
York
York
York
York
York
York
```

I'm trying to incorporate it so that I can make multiple pie charts all at once using the following:

```
Charts.Add2
ActiveChart.SetSourceData Source:=Range("'MainSheet'!$T$3:$T$14")
ActiveChart.ChartType = xlPie
ActiveChart.SetElement (msoElementLegendRight)
ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(1).XValues = "='MainSheet'!$I$4:$I$14"
Sheets("MainSheet").Select
```

Download link for example excel file: https://mega.co.nz/#!PhgWTB7a!Ie0HzaA66-vsR8nDpsQzsSlLZ9A4egoDzNtuWNR8uhU

Alternative Download link: https://www.dropbox.com/s/f44be4vj2b82lx1/Example_Pies.xlsx

I have no idea how to do this so I would much appreciate the help.

Comment: what are you looking for a macro or a function and what have you tried? what do you need the ranges for? how are you going to search them? Are you going to prompt for the location and then return the coordinates? How is your data going to be presented?

Comment: You can either do this manually by using the `COUNTIF` formula and then manually deleting the rows or if you want to use VBA then you can use the `application.worksheetfunction.countif` and then reverse loop through the rows to delete the rows if the `countif` is greater than 10.

Comment: @mehow Well, I'm trying to incorporate it into creating multiple pie charts automatically. I'm just wanting to return the .Address

Comment: @SiddharthRout I don't truly understand the countifs statement, I use it once in one delete part but I don't want to delete any more data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**MASSIVE EDIT:**

As per uploaded file, here is a working code. Optimization is up to you. **TRIED AND TESTED AND WORKING.**

```
Sub CreateCharts()

    Dim Rng1 As Range, Rng2 As Range, Rng3 As Range
    Dim Val1 As Range, Val2 As Range, Val3 As Range
    Dim RngNames As Range

    Set RngNames = Sheets("MainSheet").Range("C4:C60")

    Set Rng1 = Range(GetTopRange(RngNames, "London", 10)).Offset(0, 6)
    Set Rng2 = Range(GetTopRange(RngNames, "Newcastle", 10)).Offset(0, 6)
    Set Rng3 = Range(GetTopRange(RngNames, "York", 10)).Offset(0, 6)

    Set Val1 = Rng1.Offset(0, 11)
    Set Val2 = Rng2.Offset(0, 11)
    Set Val3 = Rng3.Offset(0, 11)

    AddChart Rng1, Val1, "London"
    AddChart Rng2, Val2, "Newcastle"
    AddChart Rng3, Val3, "York"

End Sub

Sub AddChart(rLabel As Range, rValues As Range, sTitle As String)
    Dim Cht As Chart
    Set Cht = Charts.Add
    With Cht
        .Name = sTitle
        .ChartType = xlPie
        .SetSourceData Source:=Union(rLabel, rValues)
        '.HasTitle = True
        .ChartTitle.Characters.Text = sTitle
    End With
End Sub

Function GetTopRange(Rng As Range, StrLine As String, NumCount As Long) As String
    Application.Volatile
    Dim Cell As Range, URng As Range
    For Each Cell In Rng.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants)
        If Cell.Value = StrLine Then
            If URng Is Nothing Then
                Set URng = Cell
            Else
                Set URng = Union(URng, Cell)
            End If
            If URng.Cells.Count = NumCount Then
                Exit For
            End If
        End If
    Next Cell
    GetTopRange = URng.Address
End Function
```

Thanks.

Comment: I don't want to be having to give the names to search for in the ranges, it's for the code added in my original post so that it will instantly created multiple pie charts for the list of data. In my example it would only do 3 graphs but my real sheets it would be 50+  charts regularly.

Comment: Do you know how to incorporate functions into your subroutine?

Comment: Some codes yes, but this code no. I can't even get your exact code to work in my example (I'm running it in excel 2013 and it just shows #Value)

Comment: Is it alright to get a copy of your workbook? If possible, replace all sensitive info with dummy data and upload it to WikiUpload or somesuch. I have a hunch this is being approached in the wrong way.

Comment: I've added two links (just incase mega is blocked) to my original document of what I'm essentially trying to achieve. See the charts for the example of the charts that I'm trying to automaticaly create.

Comment: Saw your file. Which column is the one you want for Axis Labels? I saw that you highlighted four columns for the label. That's a bit messy.

Comment: Took the liberty of using Column I for the usernames as that seems to make more sense. The above code is working. Optimization is up to you. My modified file [is uploaded here](http://www.wikiupload.com/4GW7W4W28HFV9X3). Click on the yellow button to run the macro.

Comment: Interesting code, It however has major problems with what I'm doing because it requires me to have to have to device the ranges and names in "CreateCharts()" my data is different all the time and in some circumstances has 50+ charts to create, also it errors out on `.ChartTitle.Characters.Text = sTitle` as sTitle is empty for some reason

Comment: The above code is a framework of sorts. Looping over a unique list of names will allow you to create dozens of sheets. That part, however, I leave to you. Also, replace the code inside the file with the above. `.HasTitle` is a tricky property and if it doesn't turn on the title box, the next line will throw an error. :)

Answer (score 0):

My 2c:

```
Function TopRange(DataRange As Range, v)
Dim f As Range
    Set f = DataRange.Find(v, , xlValues, xlWhole)
    If Not f Is Nothing Then
        TopRange = f.Resize(Application.Min( _
             Application.CountIf(DataRange, v), 10)).Address()
    Else
        TopRange = "not found"
    End If
End Function
```

Comment: Having a bit of a problem using this, I can't figure out hwo to use it :S